# What happened to include / stream filters in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, goaop, php-7.4

Go! AOP framework was using stream filters with include statement in order to perform proxies generation. It worked well in PHP 7.3, but now after PHP 7.4 beta 2 release it looks like something has changed.

Unfortunately stream filters have poor documentation, so I could not check what is going one. Maybe someone more experienced would know.

Check following sample code:

```
// index.php

include __DIR__ . '/SampleFilter.php';
SampleFilter::register();

$uri = 'php://filter/read=sample.filter/resource='. __DIR__ . '/Sample.php';

$content = file_get_contents($uri);

include $uri;
Sample::printIt();
```

```
// SampleFilter.php

class SampleFilter extends php_user_filter
{
    public const PHP_FILTER_READ = 'php://filter/read=';
    public const FILTER_IDENTIFIER = 'sample.filter';

    protected $data = '';
    protected static $filterId;

    public static function register(string $filterId = self::FILTER_IDENTIFIER) : void
    {
        if (!empty(self::$filterId)) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException('Stream filter already registered');
        }

        $result = stream_filter_register($filterId, __CLASS__);
        if ($result === false)
        {
            throw new Exception('Stream filter was not registered');
        }

        self::$filterId = $filterId;
    }

    public static function getId() : string
    {
        if (empty(self::$filterId))
        {
            throw new Exception('Stream filter was not registered');
        }

        return self::$filterId;
    }

    public function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    {
        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in))
        {
            $this->data .= $bucket->data;
        }

        if ($closing || feof($this->stream))
        {
            $consumed = strlen($this->data);

            echo '<h2>Before</h2><pre>'. htmlentities($this->data) .'</pre>';
            $this->data = str_replace('text', 'text!!!!!!!!', $this->data);
            echo '<h2>After</h2><pre>'. htmlentities($this->data) .'</pre>';

            $bucket = stream_bucket_new($this->stream, $this->data);
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);

            return PSFS_PASS_ON;
        }

        return PSFS_FEED_ME;
    }

}
```

```
// Sample.php

class Sample
{

    public static function printIt()
    {
        echo 'text';
    }

}
```

As you can see $content has properly modified code (full).
But while include'ing that file it looks like code is striped to original file length. PHP prints error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /(...)/Sample.php on line 9`

Line 9 is where it exceeds original file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78406), introduced in the PHP7.4. It have been already fixed in the latest version.